# Installing Ubuntu: [drm:drm_edid_block_valid [drm]] *ERROR* EDID has major version 0, instead of 1

Tags: ubuntu

I'm installing Ubuntu on a laptopt via a bootable USB. The installation goes smoothly until it's time to restart and boot into the system, and which point I'm stuck on a terminal screen with the error messag in the title (excluding "Installing Ubuntu: ") several times in a row, preceeded by a few rows of 0s, one ending in "fc". I think that this is an issue with NVidia drivers, or so I assume from what I've seen by googling the issue. But I can't install those drivers on my Ubuntu partition (it's dual booting with Windows 10) because I can't get into Ubuntu in the first place. I've never encountered this error while installing any Linux distro before.